# AS3 - preventDefault() doesn't work in fullscreen (AIR)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am trying to make a fullscreen program in air that does not become windowed when you press escape. Why is my program not working as it should, and how should make it work correct?

Code:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.desktop.*;
import flash.text.*;

public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main():void 
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandeler);

    }

    private function keyDownHandeler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) 
        {
            trace("Hello");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you cannot stop user from escaping and exit fullscreen, this is a security that cannot be by-passed and is meant to prevent ... well just what you are trying to do whatever it is.

Comment: I want to make a game that is in fullscreen mode, and I want to make a menu pop up when you press escape. Thats why I want to prevent entering windowed mode. Are there no way of making that?

Comment: As BotMaster told you - no. At least not with pure AS3.

Comment: Not even in AIR? Sorry if i ask alot of stupid questions :3

Comment: it's possible but only starting with AIR 15. preventDefault must then be used on esc key, displaystatechange, and event.closing.

Comment: And how would you do that?

Comment: And why doesn't the keyDownHandeler function get called at all?

Comment: You're positive your Keydown handler isn't running?  I'm suprised you're not getting errors with all the `stage` references in your `Main` constructor.  You should be adding an `this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ...)` listener before referencing `stage`

Comment: Try adding the key listener to the native application instead of stage.   `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeybaordEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);`

Comment: Now the keyDownHandler is being called correctly. But could someone explain how I can solve the escape button problem? That would be great :)

Comment: using `e.preventDefault()` on the key down handler works for me. (AIR 3.9)

Comment: I have AIR 15 i Think, should I change to 3.9?

Comment: Maybe they have changed how it works? I don't know, going to try using air 3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new project (FlashDevelop) targeting AIR 14 (also successfully tried AIR 3.9) with the following document class file:

```
package 
{
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowRenderMode;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowSystemChrome;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            if(e) removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyUpHandler);

            var content:Sprite = new Sprite();
            content.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);
            content.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 500);
            content.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(content);

            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreen);

            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        }

        private function fullScreen(e:Event):void {
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        }

        protected function keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            switch(event.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.ESCAPE:
                    trace("ESCAPE");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    break;

                default:
                    trace("UNHANDLED KEY: ", event.keyCode);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

It worked as expected. When hitting escape, the `preventDefault()` method on the key event successfully kept the application in full-screen.

Notes:
It has to be on the key down. Key up had no effect.   The result was the same with the key down listener on the `stage` or the `nativeApplication`.